# Import a VS2010 csproj in a VS2005 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, csproj

I want to import a .csproj create with VS2010 in my VS2005 solution. But I have the following message :

> The imported project "C:\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I don't know how to import my .csproj.

Is it possible to have 2 sln files (a vs2010 sln file and a vs2005 sln file) with the same csproj ? Or Should i copy each csproj for each sln file ?

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit the .csproj file by hand to make it compatible with VS2005.  Open it in notepad.exe, open another VS2005 .csproj file so that you can compare.

Focus on the `<Import Project="xxxx">` line near the bottom of the file, that's the one that is producing the error message.  There are no doubt others, I don't have VS2005 anymore to check.  Mixing and matching like this is of course best avoided, VS2010 has little trouble opening VS2005 projects after it converts them.

Comment: FYI... That seemed to work for me. I just changed `<Import Project="$MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CShar.targs" />` to `<Import Project="$MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CShar.targs" />` and VS2005 seemed to take it.